# JPanel.remove not working with JButton actionListener?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jbutton

So I am making a simple test program and I have added two buttons at the bottom of the JFrame to go forwards and backwards between questions. This is done by having a static int called page at the top of the program that is initialized to 0 at the start of the program. I have all my questions as classes that extend JPanel and they are in an ArrayList. when the forward button is pressed the current question panel is removed as planned and the page increments then adds the question from the ArrayList at the page index. This all works perfectly but when I press the previous question button all that happens is the page variable decrements and the same question is shown. What have I done Wrong?

```
JButton backward = new JButton("Previous Question");
JButton forward = new JButton("Next Question");

backward.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {
    if(page > 0)
    {
        panel.remove((Component) questions.get(page));
        page--;
        panel.add((Component) questions.get(page), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
});

forward.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {
    if(page < questions.size() - 1)
    {
        panel.remove((Component) questions.get(page));
        page++;
        panel.add((Component) questions.get(page), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    frame.setVisible(true);
});
```

Comment: You're not calling `revalidate()` and then `repaint()` on the container after changing components, but having said this, you should be using the right tool for the job, a CardLayout. The tutorial can be found here: [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).